# OERP (ODOO9) How to make a default legend selected in the graph

Tags: odoo

How to make a default legend selected in the graph while it open ,
in my code i have used default odoo graph view and now i am getting that all the legends are selected by default in this i need only one legend should be selected by default remaining legends should be unselected

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HREQt.png)

Comment: What do you mean over here? What is a `legend`?

Comment: legend is a radiobutton in the graph

Comment: hi George i  have added a image in the question pleas see it

Answer (score 0):

You will need to customise the widget that operates on the graph view that interests you, override the widget's start function, search using jquery the element and send an onclick event to it.

The widget that you need to override is named web.GraphView on v9. For instructions on how to extend a widgets functionality refer to the [documentation](http://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/web.html) according to your version of odoo.